# Как объедеинить множества

Tags: python-3.x

```
ids = {'user1': [213, 213, 213, 15, 213],
       'user2': [54, 54, 119, 119, 119],
       'user3': [213, 98, 98, 35]}

for i in ids.values():
    i1 = set(i)
    print(i1)
```

Я отсортировал списки превратив их в множества, что бы в списках не было повторений. Теперь мне надо все эти множества поместить в один список, я бы мог это сделать через '|' , но все эти множества уже в одной переменной. Подскажите как поступить? Может вообще надо по другому сделать ?

Comment: Непонятно, какой конкретно результат вы хотите получить в итоге? Список чисел? Множество чисел? Список множеств чисел?

Comment: Список чисел, сейчас множества

Answer (score 0):

Можно так:

```
ids = {
    'user1': [213, 213, 213, 15, 213],
    'user2': [54, 54, 119, 119, 119],
    'user3': [213, 98, 98, 35],
}

result = set()
for i in ids.values():
    result |= set(i)
print(result)
```